# Setting up Rails Controller for the through in has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a rails web app with a many-to-many through model. The application is to allow users to populate their dashboard with a number of pre-defined "widgets". So I have a table of users (created and managed by devise) and a table of widgets. All good. So to manage the through bit, I have a table of "subscriptons". Here are my models:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :widget
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :widget_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :widgets, through: :subscriptions
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end
```

However, I don't really understand how to create the subscriptions. I would ideally like the create form to just have a selector to choose from all available widgets and then user the current `user:id` but I am not sure how this would work, here is my controller:

```
  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @subscription = @user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscription.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'subscription was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscription }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction, as I can't understand how this is done from the official docs and haven't found any good tutorials relating to this.

Comment: Are there any other attributes on subscription?  or just the ids for the associations?

Comment: @j-dexx I think that for what I need to achieve it only needs to define the association.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have any other attributes on subscriptions you can use the `widget_ids=` method that your `has_many` creates on user

Controller

```
class UserSubscriptionsController
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update(user_subscription_params)
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Subscriptions updated"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def user_subscription_params
    params.require(:user).permit(widget_ids: [])
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_subscription_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :widget_ids, Widget.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The routes in my example would have

```
resource :user_subscription, only: [:edit, :update]
```

But obviously you can amend based on what you want your routes to be.
Rails will automatically create the subscriptions when updating the user.

You could instead just use the `collection_check_boxes` when editing a user normally if you wanted.  There is also `collection_select`

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is such a help! What would the create and new controllers look like?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I wouldn't have a new or create personally, as you're always technically editing the user and you'll have the `User` controller actually creating the user.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I am a bit confused. I thought of creating a new subscription item, but this is adding a subscription object to my user, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, `has_many through` allows you to pass the `widget_ids` to the user, and rails will then automatically create the subscriptions for you.

Comment: Amazing - thank you! Do I need to create a new UserSubscriptions Controller for that to work, atm I only have `subscriptions_controller` and `widgets_controller`

Comment: No, you could simply add it to your normal form for the user if you want.  You could use your subscriptions controller.

Comment: the `User_Subscription_params` is throwing error `param is missing or the value is empty: user`

Comment: It shouldn't be, because the form is bound to the user.  Are you using form_for?

Comment: Yes, I have got the exact snippet you posted in views/subscriptions/_form.html.erb, where new.html.erb is just `<%= render 'form' %>` the url where this error is thrown is /subscriptions

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards [code](https://github.com/j-dexx/user_widgets) you must have done something differently.  I had one error, need to specify widget_ids as an array, changed that in my answer.  if you clone repo and `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed` it works

Answer (score 0):

You can save data like this using subscription form.

```
  = form_for @subscription do |f|
   = f.select :widget_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Widget.all, "id", "title"), {}, {:class => "form-control select" }
   = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
   #other subscription fields
   = f.submit
```